# Iterating through a JSON array and returning a subset of elements

Tags: arrays, json, loops

I'm new to JS and trying to figure out how to iterate through a json array and return only a **subset** of elements. Specifically I would like to know how to return only the **'first_name'** and **'last_name'** from the Mock data in the attached code snippet. It seems like it should be straightforward but I'm scratching my head.

```js
let people =  [{"id":1,"first_name":"Talbert","last_name":"Kohnert","email":"tkohnert0@wisc.edu","country":"Indonesia"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Ruthie","last_name":"McKleod","email":"rmckleod1@gizmodo.com","country":"Sweden"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Lenore","last_name":"Foister","email":"lfoister2@epa.gov","country":"Nicaragua"}]

people.forEach(person => {
    for (let key in person) {
        console.log(`${key} => ${person[key]}`);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous way of achieving this output. One of most frequently used method is using `map()` of es6.

```
let people =  [{"id":1,"first_name":"Talbert","last_name":"Kohnert","email":"tkohnert0@wisc.edu","country":"Indonesia"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Ruthie","last_name":"McKleod","email":"rmckleod1@gizmodo.com","country":"Sweden"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Lenore","last_name":"Foister","email":"lfoister2@epa.gov","country":"Nicaragua"}]

//by map method
people.map((person,index)=>{
     console.log(`${person.first_name} ${person.last_name}`)
})

// by forEach
people.forEach(person => {
        console.log(`${person.first_name} ${person.last_name}`)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammed. You guys have shown me at least 3 different solutions to my original problem. This community is super!

Comment: Please mark it green tick. So that jn future other dev can get help

Comment: Happy to mark the green tick but how or where?

Comment: See to the left of my response there is upward array click that it means that this is correct solution also click on right Mark below that, it verified it. @Les

Answer (score 1):

Use the element names

```js
people.forEach(person => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(person) + "\n");
  console.log(person["first_name"], person["last_name"], "\n");
});
```

Produces this output:

```
{"id":1,"first_name":"Talbert","last_name":"Kohnert","email":"tkohnert0@wisc.edu","country":"Indonesia"}
Talbert Kohnert 


{"id":2,"first_name":"Ruthie","last_name":"McKleod","email":"rmckleod1@gizmodo.com","country":"Sweden"}
Ruthie McKleod 

{"id":3,"first_name":"Lenore","last_name":"Foister","email":"lfoister2@epa.gov","country":"Nicaragua"}
Lenore Foister
```

Comment: Thanks James. You guys have shown me at least 3 different solutions to my original problem. This community is super!

Answer (score 1):

You can try Object [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) of ES6 to achieve the requirement.

**Working Demo :**

```js
let people =  [{"id":1,"first_name":"Talbert","last_name":"Kohnert","email":"tkohnert0@wisc.edu","country":"Indonesia"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Ruthie","last_name":"McKleod","email":"rmckleod1@gizmodo.com","country":"Sweden"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Lenore","last_name":"Foister","email":"lfoister2@epa.gov","country":"Nicaragua"}];

let res = people.map(({first_name, last_name}) => first_name + ' ' + last_name);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using the map function.
map lets you iterate over each item in the array and return a new value for each iteration while returning a new array, so for your case:

```js
let people =  [
 {"id":1,"first_name":"Talbert","last_name":"Kohnert","email":"tkohnert0@wisc.edu","country":"Indonesia"},
 {"id":2,"first_name":"Ruthie","last_name":"McKleod","email":"rmckleod1@gizmodo.com","country":"Sweden"},
 {"id":3,"first_name":"Lenore","last_name":"Foister","email":"lfoister2@epa.gov","country":"Nicaragua"}
]

const newArray = people.map((person) => {
  return {
   first_name: person.first_name,
   last_name: person.last_name
  }
})

console.log(newArray)
```

here you get a new array with just the properties you need.

Comment: Thanks for this. Simple and elegant, just what I was looking for!